# How to connect to a VPN on linux when the client is only available on Windows

Tags: linux, vpn, network-protocols

I have to connect to a vpn with my linux machine, the problem is that the client is available only for windows (ZyWall SecuExtender).
Now, is there a way to connect to the vpn without the client? (maybe with some other tool available on linux).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Zyxel has created a tutorial on how to access the VPN on Linux
by using Linux StrongSwan.

You may find the tutorial at
[How to establish client to site VPN to ATP
series with Linux StrongSwan](https://us.v-cdn.net/6029482/uploads/editor/ag/r1dy8td7fndc.pdf).

I found this tutorial in an answer on the post
[I can connect from Windows 10, but cant from linux](https://community.zyxel.com/en/discussion/9890/i-can-connect-from-windows-10-but-cant-from-linux).

The tutorial is too long to reproduce here and isn't simple.
If it proves to be too complex, you might consider creating a Windows
virtual machine.